Can SMART data be reset to hide errors?
I have HDDs purchased on Aliexpress inside a Kesu case. CrystalDiskInfo says they are in good health and have only been used for a few hours. I suspect that something has changed and I wondered if SMART was reset or the firmware was modified to hide errors. I performed a QuickScan with Victoria and found no errors.
Is Victoria's QuickScan able to reveal the truth if the HDD is in good or bad health for data archiving? In theory, SMART was reset or the firmware was modified? Or is a Full Scan 100% necessary to update SMART?


https://forum.hddguru.com/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=44652

AFAIK, S.M.A.R.T. is read-only and can't be reset since only the drive's firmware is able to write to it. HDD manufacturers would be able to since they have direct access to the firmware, but AFAIK, there is no way a user can reset S.M.A.R.T since there's no way for a user to have anything other than read-only access (resetting values would require write access).

So why do several Aliexpress HDDs look used but when you open crystaldiskinfo they appear to be in good health and have been used for 2 or 3 hours? They must have changed something

This question is similar to: Reset SMART on Hard Drive. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

So why do several Aliexpress HDDs.  The question is why do you keep buying them?  Why would you trust a dubious source?  Maybe its a fake drive, who knows!
